# C# IPriorityQueue in mono develop /unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

Newb here, I'm trying to use IPriorityQueue (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341766(v=vs.110).aspx), with MonoDevelop, but it cannot find it. I'm I missing the assembly? the start of my code looks like...

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



/// <summary>
/// Represents a binary heap data structure capable of storing generic key-value pairs.
/// </summary>
public class BinaryHeap<TKey, TValue> : IPriorityQueue<TKey, TValue>
    where TKey : System.IComparable
{
```

what do I need to do to get this functionality? Thanks.

Comment: What version of unity are you using? IPriorityQueue seems to require .net 3.5. perhaps an older version of unity doesn't support that feature.

Comment: Why do you even need the interface, the only thing it is used for is interop with STL/CLR which you won't be using with Unity.

Comment: I ended up scouring the net and found that c5 library for c# has it's own implementation of a priority queue. Currently trying to figure out how to use it.